# Bluetooth with QtonPi using Qt5

Tags: bluetooth, libraries, raspberry-pi, qt5, qtonpi

I'm trying to compile the bluetooth chat example to be used on Raspberry Pi platform.
I installed the QtonPi following this procedure [QtonPi App SDK](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Create)

At first I loaded the chat example project and tried to compile it straight away.
Errors with missing bluetooth libraries.

I searched in the folders, but no qtconnectivity !!

I tried to compile the missing library by my own but I'm stuck.

So, how should I proceed to have those libraries working with the raspberry Pi QT5 SDK working ?

Any advice ? I feel a bit lost as I'm not an experimented programmer when comes the time to add libraries.

Thanks.

Cedric

Comment: You might have more luck on http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com

Comment: I'll check that, thanks a lot.